# Cannot put files larger than 6mb to S3 with CORS, no error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Im using CORS to upload files to amazon s3 via the javascript sdk.
Smaller files are being put correctly, however anything around 6mb or larger does not show up in my bucket. I do not get any aws error at all. Is there is a size limitation with my method, or is my method is breaking some how?

Server side:

```
    app.get('/sign', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    aws.config.update({
        accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
        secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_KEY,
        "region": "us-west-2"
    });
    var s3 = new aws.S3();
    var params = {
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
        Key: req.query.file_name,
        Expires: 3000,
        ContentType: req.query.file_type,
        ACL: 'public-read'
    }

    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        console.log(req.query);
        res.json({
            signed_request: data,
            url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/' + S3_BUCKET + '/' + req.query.file_name
        })
    })

})
```

Client side:

```
function upload(file, signed_request, url, done) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open("PUT", signed_request)
    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-amz-acl', 'public-read')
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            done()
        }
    }

    xhr.send(file)
}

function sign_request(file, done) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    var uid = guid();
    document.getElementById("videoId").value = uid;
    xhr.open("GET", "/sign?file_name=" + uid + "&file_type=" + file.type)



    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
            done(response)
        }
    }

    xhr.send()
}

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
    var file = document.getElementById("video").files[0];
    if (!file) return

    sign_request(file, function(response) {
        upload(file, response.signed_request, response.url, function() {
            document.getElementById("preview").src = response.url
        })
    })
}
```

And my CORS properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:7000</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>30000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-server-side-encryption</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-request-id</ExposeHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>x-amz-id-2</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: In `xhr.onload = function() { ...` you're not checking for errors... are you?  You're apparently only looking for 200 (success).  What do you see in the S3 log?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have added logging to the xhr.onload function. What I have found is that if the file is smaller than 6mb I get a 200 status, otherwise the function never hets hit, I never get a status 200 or otherwise.